# Why don't Ally's clothes get damaged or dirty in T-Rex: Back to the Cretaceous?

Tags: t-rex-back-to-the-cretaceous

None of Ally’s clothing sustained any damage during her time-travelling adventure. Nor did her clothes get dirty, and even her necklace, after she loses it, is found (in fossil strata by her dad) none the worse for wear. How could that be?

Comment: Because it's a movie. This is one of those rare cases where I really don't think there's any other answer.

Comment: Maybe the magic of inhaling that egg dust protected her clothing.

Comment: https://youtu.be/LF7RTV5xU9w - What's weird is that she kneels in dirt at one point, then her jeans are clean in the next shot

Comment: This & many other reasons why this has been unfavourably compared to 'Plan 9 from Outer Space'.

Comment: [Obligatory TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeautyIsNeverTarnished)

Comment: Not nearly as bad as the Schwarzenegger movie _Commando_ in which he rolls a Porsche on its side, and is then seen pushing it back upright with no damage to the side panels...

Comment: @Tetsujin - Why, it's almost like this was intended to be shown to schoolchildren at the iMax at Epcot

Comment: It’s ultimately ambiguous whether Ally did time travel or was merely hallucinating.

Comment: @LouisHolmes - Well, except for the *"[It was real all along!](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealAfterAll)"* ending.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealAfterAll

Answer (score 3):

In-universe there isn't much to explain it. She certainly *should* be dirty, having [waded through a swamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl95Z.png), [fallen on her butt in the dirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF0Zc.png) and [knelt in mud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2aVx.png) on several occasions. The simplest explanation is that **she isn't actually time-traveling**, and is basically just sat in the museum having an extended hallucination, courtesy of whatever drugs her father was smuggling back inside the dinosaur eggs.

Note that her 'time travel' relates very strongly to the exhibitions in the museum
(e,g, she looks at a T-rex skeleton and lo and behold, she meets a friendly T-rex, she goes to the painting gallery and she's transported to meet Barnum Brown who, surprisingly, isn't immediately intrigued by her anachronistic clothing (including jeans that would be considered indecently tight by the standards of the late 1800s, and a futuristic plastic headband made of materials that won't be invented for nearly fifty years after her meeting with him), etc.

All of this suggests that she's not actually in the swamps and forests, and that we're just watching her stumbling around a museum having a bad trip.